# is it possible to obtain object movement from affine registration?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, affinetransform, image-registration

My question is theoretical - algorithmic.

I have a video of some object, taken from a static calibrated camera.

I also have the affine transformation matrix of the object from one frame to the consecutive frame.
meaning, for each pixel in the tracked object, i have the correspoding pixel in the next frame.

Is it theoretically possible to obtain world coordinates of the tracked object using its projected affine transformation over time?

Couldn't use google to my advantage here, as I'm not sure what to search for.

would appreciate any leads, as well as answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some parameters you should know before you can find object coordinate in the real world. If you have the camera coordinates you can calculate the object distance using pinhole project formula.

I found a very good explanation for pinhole formula [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/12440).